# how to fire alarm after every 5 minute

Tags: android, alarmmanager

**i want snooze functionality in my app which will fire alarm after every 5 min**
i am making an app in which alarm is firing on the date user chooses with a dialog box having  2 buttons close and snooze close button is working fine but snooze crashes the application without showing any error 
 here is my code:

```
Button snooze = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_snooze);
snooze.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     mMediaPlayer.stop();
                     Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                     Intent intent = new Intent();
                     intent.setAction("action_e");
                     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, intent, 0);

                     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                     alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5*60*1000, pendingIntent);

                     //DialogActivity.this.finish ();
                }
            });
```

in alarm reciving class i am just printing a toast msg to chk that alarm is fired
where i am doing wrong?

Comment: where do you initilize context variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this following code in your snooze button click.

```
snooze.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                finish();

                // meidaPlayer.stop();
                Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cal = (Calendar) today.clone();


                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+ 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 5);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                setAlarm(cal);

            }
        });

}
```

And write the method of **setAlram()** like the following.

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

        if (targetCal.get(Calendar.HOUR) > 12)
            hours = targetCal.get(Calendar.HOUR) - 12;
        else
            hours = targetCal.get(Calendar.HOUR);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Alaram set to" + hours + ":" + targetCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // String time_selected = hours + ":" + targetCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        if (targetCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }

    }
```

hope it will helps you.May know your feedback.

Comment: can u tell me what type of variable is hours

Comment: @user2750762:-int hours;

Comment: thanks, the code is working fine but there is one more issue Now the alarm is continiously ringing after and doesn't recognize the close button

Comment: Please accept if it will works.And for stop the ringing you have to cancel the alarm wherever you want.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake i was not stopping media player on snooze click THANKS AGAIN

Comment: @user2750762:-Ok..np..:)

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + 5*60*1000,alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

write this code in snooze `onclick()` method i hope it will help you

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

//play the alarm here

        }
        }, 5000);
```